# Why `wait` for the child when `read` could supposedly block the parent process in pipe?

Tags: c, process, pipe, ipc, wait

I was learning `pipe` and communication between processes and I saw the following code to ping-pong a byte between parent and child processes:

```
int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int p[2];
    char buf[2];
    char *send = "a", *rec = "b";
    pipe(p);

    int pid = fork(); 
    if(pid == 0){

        if(read(p[0], buf, 1) != 1){
            fprintf(2, "child failed to read byte from parent.\n");
            exit(1);
        };
        close(p[0]);

        printf("%d: received ping\n",getpid());

        if(write(p[1], rec, 1) != 1){
            fprintf(2, "child failed to send byte to parent.\n");
            exit(1);
        };

        close(p[1]); 
        exit(0);

    } else if(pid > 0){
        
        if(write(p[1], send, 1) !=1){
            fprintf(2, "parent failed to send byte to child.\n");
            exit(1);
        };

        close(p[1]); 

        wait(0);
        
        if(read(p[0], buf, 1) != 1) { 
            fprintf(2, "parent failed to read byte back from child.\n");
            exit(1);
        };
        close(p[0]);

        printf("%d: received pong\n", getpid());

        exit(0);
    }
    else exit(1);
}
```

This code works. However, after learning that

> If no data is available, a read on a pipe waits for either data to be written or for all file descriptors
> referring to the write end to be closed; in the latter case, read will return 0, just as if the end of
> a data file had been reached.

I began to have some doubts. The `wait(0)` in the parent process seems now redundant, for the `read` in the parent process would not run before the child process writes, which in some way acted as a `wait()`.

So, I removed the `wait(0)` line, and the code would still be able to print "received pong" **but no more "received ping"**, which means the child did not perform the `read` as expected. This confuses me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify: [`wait`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html) is used by a parent process to wait for any child process to *terminate*, and to release the system information associated with it (commonly known as *reaping* a *zombie process*). Its functionality is only tangentially related to writing/reading to/from pipes, in that it vaguely falls under the umbrella of inter-process communication.

Without `wait` in between the `write` and `read` of the parent process, it is very likely that the parent process will simply read the byte it has written to the pipe *before* the child process even gets CPU time. Both processes are reading and writing to the **same** pipe, after all. In this case, the parent process fails to *reap* the child process properly by exiting without waiting. The child becomes an *orphan process*, since it will block forever, trying to read a byte from the pipe, as it still has the write end of the pipe open.

With `wait` present, the parent process writes a byte to the pipe, and then blocks waiting for the child process to terminate. At approximately the same time the child process reads a byte (possibly blocking), then writes a byte, then terminates. After the child terminates, the parent process *reaps* the child process, and then reads a byte.

Leave the `wait` where it is, or use *two pipes* for bidirectional communication and `close` the unused ends of each more aggressively (i.e., as early as possible) where appropriate. Be wary of [deadlocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock).